# SQLAlchemy Double Inner Join on multiple foreign keys

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

***Please see update at bottom***

I have three classes. Let's call them `Post`, `PostVersion`, and `Tag`. (This is for an internal version control system in a web app, perhaps similar to StackOverflow, though I'm unsure of their implementation strategy). I sort of use terminology from git to understand it. These are highly simplified versions of the classes for the purposes of this question:

```
class Post(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    author_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("user.id"))
    author = db.relationship("User", backref="posts")
    head_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("post_version.id"))
    HEAD = db.relationship("PostVersion", foreign_keys=[head_id])
    added = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow)

class PostVersion(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    editor_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("user.id"))
    editor = db.relationship("User")
    previous_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("post_version.id"), default=None)
    previous = db.relationship("PostVersion")
    pointer_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("post.id"))
    pointer = db.relationship("Post", foreign_keys=[pointer_id])
    post = db.Column(db.Text)
    modified = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow)
    tag_1_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("tag.id"), default=None)
    tag_2_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("tag.id"), default=None)
    tag_3_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("tag.id"), default=None)
    tag_4_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("tag.id"), default=None)
    tag_5_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("tag.id"), default=None)
    tag_1 = db.relationship("Tag", foreign_keys=[tag_1_id])
    tag_2 = db.relationship("Tag", foreign_keys=[tag_2_id])
    tag_3 = db.relationship("Tag", foreign_keys=[tag_3_id])
    tag_4 = db.relationship("Tag", foreign_keys=[tag_4_id])
    tag_5 = db.relationship("Tag", foreign_keys=[tag_5_id])

class Tag(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    tag = db.Column(db.String(128))
```

To make a new post, I create both a Post and an initial `PostVersion` to which `Post.head_id` points. Every time an edit is made, a new `PostVersion` is created pointing to the previous `PostVersion`, and the `Post.head_id` is reset to point to the new `PostVersion`. To reset the post version to an earlier version--well, I haven't gotten that far but it seems trivial to either copy the previous version or just reset the pointer to the previous version.

My question is this, though: how can I write a relationship between `Post` and `Tag` such that

1. `Post.tags` would be a list of all the tags the current `PostVersion` contains, and
2. `Tag.posts` would be a list of all the `Post`'s that currently have that particular tag?

The first condition seems easy enough, a simple method

```
def get_tags(self):
    t = []
    if self.HEAD.tag_1:
        t.append(self.HEAD.tag_1)
    if self.HEAD.tag_2:
        t.append(self.HEAD.tag_2)
    if self.HEAD.tag_3:
        t.append(self.HEAD.tag_3)
    if self.HEAD.tag_4:
        t.append(self.HEAD.tag_4)
    if self.HEAD.tag_5:
        t.append(self.HEAD.tag_5)
    return t
```

does the trick just fine for now, but the second condition is almost intractable for me right now. I currently use an obnoxious method in Tag where I query for all the `PostVersion`'s with the tag using an `or_` filter:

```
def get_posts(self):
    edits = PostVersion.query.filter(or_(
         PostVersion.tag_1_id==self.id,
         PostVersion.tag_2_id==self.id,
         PostVersion.tag_3_id==self.id,
         PostVersion.tag_4_id==self.id,
         PostVersion.tag_5_id==self.id,
         ).order_by(PostVersion.modified.desc()).all()
    posts = []
    for e in edits:
        if self in e.pointer.get_tags() and e.pointer not in posts:
            posts.append(e.pointer)
    return posts
```

This is horribly inefficient and I cannot paginate the results.

I know this would be a secondary join from `Post` to `Tag` or `Tag` to `Post` through `PostVersion`, but it would have to be a secondary join on an or, and I have no clue how to even start to write that.

Looking back on my code I'm beginning to wonder why some of these relationships require the `foreign_keys` parameter to be defined and others don't. I'm thinking it's relating to where they're defined (immediately following the FK id column or not) and noticing that there's a list for the `foreign_keys`, I'm thinking *that's* how I could define it. But I'm unsure how to pursue this.

I'm also wondering now if I could dispense with the `pointer_id` on `PostVersion` with a well-configured relationship. This, however, is irrelevant to the question (though the circular reference does cause headaches).

For reference, I am using Flask-SQLAlchemy, Flask-migrate, and MariaDB. I am heavily following [Miguel Grinberg's Flask Megatutorial](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-i-hello-world).

Any help or advice would be a godsend.

## UPDATE

I have devised the following mysql query that *works*, and now I need to translate it into sqlalchemy:

```
SELECT
    post.id, tag.tag 
FROM
    post
INNER JOIN
    post_version
ON
    post.head_id=post_version.id
INNER JOIN 
    tag
ON 
    post_version.tag_1_id=tag.id OR
    post_version.tag_2_id=tag.id OR
    post_version.tag_3_id=tag.id OR
    post_version.tag_4_id=tag.id OR
    post_version.tag_5_id=tag.id OR
WHERE
    tag.tag="<tag name>";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem on my own, and it really just consists of defining a primary and secondary join with an or_ in the primary:

```
posts = db.relationship("Post", secondary="post_version",
    primaryjoin="or_(Tag.id==post_version.c.tag_1_id,"
    "Tag.id==post_version.c.tag_2_id,"
    "Tag.id==post_version.c.tag_3_id,"
    "Tag.id==post_version.c.tag_4_id,"
    "Tag.id==post_version.c.tag_5_id)",
    secondaryjoin="Annotation.head_id==post_version.c.id",
    lazy="dynamic")
```

As you can see I mix table and class names. I will update the answer as I experiment to make it more regular.

Answer (score 1):

Can you change the database design, or do you have to make your app work on a DB that you can't change? If the latter, I can't help you. If you can change the design, you should do it like this:

1. Replace the linked chain of PostVersions with a one-to-many relationship from Post to PostVersions. Your "Post" class will end up having a relationship "versions" to all instances of PostVersion pertinent to that Post.
2. Replace the tag_id members with a many-to-many relationship using an additional association table.

Both methods are well-explained in the SQLAlchemy docs. Be sure to start with minimal code, testing in small non-Flask command line programs. Once you have the basic functionality down, transfer the concept to your more complicated classes. After that, ask yourself your original questions again. The answers will come much more easily.

Comment: I can change the database but I have two questions for for you: (1) How will the one-to-many table on `Post`-`PostVersion` identify _which_ `PostVersion` is the most current? Should there still be a `head_id`? I actually essentially have a one-to-many table right now based on `pointer_id` (2) I dislike the many-to-many tag approach because it (a) puts no hard-limit on tags per post and (b) does not have a built in version control system (as it stands, changing the tags of a post is a new version of the post). Is there no way to achieve this without converting to a many-to-many tags table?

Comment: I technically have between `Post` and `PostVersion` a one-to-many table (from `PostVersion.pointer_id` to `Post.id`), a one-to-one table (from `Post.head_id` to `PostVersion.id`), and a linked list (from `PostVersion.previous_id` to `PostVersion.id`)

Comment: (1) If your PostVersion table contains an autoincrement primary key ID, you just select the version with the highest ID. (2) Both the max. tag limit and the creation of new PostVersion should be implemented in the application logic, not hard-coded into the DB mechanics. Just imagine the headache if one day someone decides if there should be a limit of 4 or 6 or 10 tags per post. A general hint in programming: If you find yourself typing (or copy-and-pasting) essentially the same thing over and over, such as your five-fold tag_id condition, you know your code is seriously flawed.

Comment: Regarding your second comment: Yes, technically you have those relationships. As in, the information is there and it can be found. Practically, however, both methods are inflexible and ugly and are therefore not the way to do it. You're stuck where you are not because your're not enough of a SQL whiz but because your database is ill designed in the first place.

Comment: I'll take all that into consideration and I thank you for the advice. I was irritated by having to type the five tags over and over (and I agree), but I saw the alternative many-to-many table on the tags to result in _a lot_ of extra application logic that I saw as unnecessary. I see drawbacks in the hardcoded tags as well (such as: if someone changes tag 1 but includes the original tag_2 as tag_2, no change will be detected). I actually solved the problem on my own and will be posting the answer, but I'm upvoting yours as well because it's valid advice.