# SQLAlchemy Handling Multiple Paths In One Relationship

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

*Please note: this question is related but separate from my other currently open question [SQLAlchemy secondary join relationship on multiple foreign keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52648147/sqlalchemy-secondary-join-relationship-on-multiple-foreign-keys).*

The [SQLAlchemy documentation describes handling multiple join paths](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/join_conditions.html#handling-multiple-join-paths) in a single class ***for multiple relationships***:

```
from sqlalchemy import Integer, ForeignKey, String, Column
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship

Base = declarative_base()

class Customer(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'customer'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)

    billing_address_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("address.id"))
    shipping_address_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("address.id"))

    billing_address = relationship("Address")
    shipping_address = relationship("Address")

class Address(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'address'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    street = Column(String)
    city = Column(String)
    state = Column(String)
    zip = Column(String)
```

Within the same section the documentation shows three separate ways to define the relationship:

1. `billing_address = relationship("Address", foreign_keys=[billing_address_id])`
2. `billing_address = relationship("Address", foreign_keys="[Customer.billing_address_id]")`
3. `billing_address = relationship("Address", foreign_keys="Customer.billing_address_id")`

As you can see in (1) and (2) SQLAlchemy allows you to define a list of foreign_keys. In fact, the documentation explicitly states:

> In this specific example, the list is not necessary in any case as there’s only one Column we need: `billing_address = relationship("Address", foreign_keys="Customer.billing_address_id")`

***But I cannot determine how to use the list notation to specify multiple foreign keys in a single relationship***.

For the classes

```
class PostVersion(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    ...
    tag_1_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("tag.id"))
    tag_2_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("tag.id"))
    tag_3_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("tag.id"))
    tag_4_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("tag.id"))
    tag_5_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("tag.id"))

class Tag(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    tag = db.Column(db.String(127))
```

I have tried all of the following:

1. `tags = db.relationship("Tag", foreign_keys=[tag_1_id, tag_2_id, tag_3_id, tag_4_id, tag_5_id])` resulting in

> sqlalchemy.exc.AmbiguousForeignKeysError: Could not determine join condition between parent/child tables on relationship AnnotationVersion.tags - there are multiple foreign key paths linking the tables.  Specify the 'foreign_keys' argument, providing a list of those columns which should be counted as containing a foreign key reference to the parent table.

2. `tags = db.relationship("Tag", foreign_keys="[tag_1_id, tag_2_id, tag_3_id, tag_4_id, tag_5_id]")` resulting in

> sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: When initializing mapper Mapper|AnnotationVersion|annotation_version, expression '[tag_1_id, tag_2_id, tag_3_id, tag_4_id, tag_5_id]' failed to locate a name ("name 'tag_1_id' is not defined"). If this is a class name, consider adding this relationship() to the  class after both dependent classes have been defined.

And many others variations on the list style, using quotes inside and outside, using Table names and Class names.

I've actually solved the problem in the course of this question. Since there seems to be no direct documentation, I'll answer it myself instead of deleting this question.

Comment: Seems like an association table would be a nice fit as well, instead of having repeating foreign keys and complex joins.

Comment: @IljaEverilä , I've heard that several times, but the issue with an association table (I'm assuming you mean many-to-many on `Tag`-`PostVersion`) is that I want a hard limit on the number of tags each PostVersion can contain. I arrived at this schema basically because I thought hard about how stackoverflow might implement tags and question versioning through edits. If the tags change, that's an edit, and it's easy to store a new version of the question based on that. But that seems difficult if it's a many-to-many table. Wait. Mein gott! I think I just realized an easy way to do it! Thanks Ilj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key is to define the relationship on a primary join and specify the `uselist` parameter.

```
tags = db.relationship("Tag", primaryjoin="or_(PostVersion.tag_1_id==Tag.id,"
     "PostVersion.tag_2_id==Tag.id, PostVersion.tag_3_id==Tag.id,"
     "PostVersion.tag_4_id==Tag.id, PostVersion.tag_5_id==Tag.id)",
     uselist=True)
```